# How to automatically create a new wav file for each recorded calls with MixMonitor?

Tags: asterisk, dialplan

**Intro :** I am trying to record each calls but I don't want to append them  to a same file or overwrite it all the time. I'd like to have a file for each call. The name of the file should be the date+time when the call was made so that it is unique. I can't figure out how to do this.

**My current extension.conv :**

```
exten => 1000,1,Answer()
exten => 1000,2,MixMonitor(${DATETIME}.wav,v(0)V(0))
exten => 1000,3,Background(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/intro2168000)
```

**Problem:**

the file is only called ".wav".

Is there a way to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work on older versions of Asterisk. The `${DATETIME}` variable is deprecated and should be replaced with `${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%d%m%Y-%H:%M:%S)}` on modern versions of Asterisk.

```
exten => 1000,1,Answer()
exten => 1000,2,MixMonitor(${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%d%m%Y-%H:%M:%S)}.wav)
exten => 1000,3,Background(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/intro2168000)
```

Note your `v(0)V(0)` wasn't doing anything so can be left off.

Comment: Just tried it. It works like magic. Thanks
I em encountering some quality issues with the call though. Do you think this is related to the Background function ? Like when doing the call, the call receiver hears the caller as if he was a robot.